# Visual Studio 2015 Command Prompt and midl is not recognized issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, rpc, midl

So more or less I am just looking to better understand what I could be doing incorrectly that could be causing the issue I keep having.

Recently I have started diving into C++ Remote Procedure Call (RPC) tutorials in an attempt to create a 64 bit client application that can communicate with a 32 bit server application. I have had success in this using a combination of tutorials. Bear with me here I am getting to my main point, I just want to show the steps I followed for clarity.

Here are the steps I followed:

1. I open VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt and create an .idl file using the command "uuidgen Myfile.idl"
2. I use notepad++ to make changes to the .idl file and then save it.
3. I use the command prompt and the command "midl Myfile.idl" to build my 32 bit header file, my client proxy, and server stub C files.
4. I then use the command prompt and the command "midl x64 Myfile.idl" to build my 64 bit header file, my client proxy, and server stub C files.
5. I then create my Client and server applications combine everything and build both applications with no issue.

Now for the issue that this post is all about.

I followed those steps multiple times to change up functions defined in the .idl file and had no issues. Then this morning I get to work and attempt to follow those steps so I can add functions and my VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt can no longer recognize or find either the uuidgen.exe or the midl.exe.

Is there something I could be doing that is changing the target platform or include directories of my VS Command Prompt tool? Has anyone else experienced this?

I should also say I did not install any other applications between sessions. I also have found the only way for me to correct this issue is to completely uninstall visual studio and reinstall it. The repair feature did not correct the issue and this is the second time this has happened.

Any advice, links or remarks are definitely appreciated as well as criticism.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Something wrong with the path.  So type "path".  Big list, usually, C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64 should be in that list.  Go check if that directory is still good.

Comment: @HansPassant Yep good catch! Thank you, still new at some aspects of this. that folder did not contain any of the .exe files, but the directory above it did so I actually had to add the path to my Environment Variables.